# How to hide the prompt when executing a registry file through batch file in startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

- I have a edited some values in my registry file, and want to execute
  that `.reg` file every time when the computer starts.
- So I created a batch file and placed it in start up folder. And the
  batch file contains the following lines :

  `C:\Windows\regedit.exe /s C:\myregistry.reg`
- It works fine but it asks for confirmation every time to execute, If
  I press Yes then it run my registry file otherwise not.

So how could I automatically make it select "Yes" every time with out prompting me?

Or is there any other way, so some of my values in HKLM will be updated everytime with out prompting or anything.

Thanks,
Anchal Bhargava

Comment: Use the command line utility `reg` -- type `reg /?` for details...

Comment: The usage of `regedit.exe` requires always administrator privileges. By using `reg.exe` no administrator privileges are required for read/write access on `HKCU` and read access (query) on other registry hives, except there are special permissions set for a key which deny read access by current user. But write access on `HKLM` requires also administrator privileges on using `reg.exe`, except the key to update with the write access has special permissions to allow write access also by current user. So in general write to `HKLM` is not possible without first getting elevated to administrator.

Comment: The elevation prompt asking user for confirmation to write to `HKLM` can't be avoided on doing the registry import with a user account not being an administrator or with user account control disabled. If that would be possible, every malware application would make use of it to harm computers running on Windows.